# add multiple po files into one, the default.po

Tags: merge, internationalization

I'm trying to add a i18n support for a CakePHP plugin. I have multiple *.pot files which I've edited/translated with poedit. The thing is that I'll like to merge all the files into one default.po file.

Does anyone know how can I do that in the most easy/smart way?

Answer (score 7):

You use msgcat for that.

http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/msgcat-Invocation.html